# Using SharedPreferences to set login state and retrieving it at App launch - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an flutter app in which I have to check the login status when the app is launched and call the relevant screen accordingly.

The code used to launch the app:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() {
    return new MyAppState();
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

bool isLoggedIn;

    Future<bool> getLoginState() async{
      SharedPreferences pf =  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool loginState = pf.getBool('loginState');
      return loginState;
      // return pf.commit();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   getLoginState().then((isAuth){
      this.isLoggedIn = isAuth;
   });


    if(this.isLoggedIn) {return Container(child: Text('Logged In'));}
    else {return Container(child: Text('Not Logged In));}

  }
}
```

I am able to save the `SharedPreference` and retrieve it here, the issue is that as `getLoginState()` is an async function, `this.isLoggedIn` is null by the time the if condition is executed. The boolean assertion fails in the if statement and the app crashes.

How do I ensure that the bool variable `isLoggedIn` used in the if condition has a value when the if statement is executed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to solve this problem.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 new FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getLoginState(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.active:
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return new Text('Loading...');
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            loginState = snapshot.data;
            if(loginState) {
             return Container(child: Text('Logged In'));
            }
            else {
             return Container(child: Text('Not Logged In));
            }
          } else {
           return  Container(child: Text('Error..));
          }
      }
    },
  )
 }
```

Note: we don't need `isLoggedIn` state variable.