# Waiting for widgets to load their components

Tags: flutter

I have a Widget screen which has several widget components that fetch data from a server. I would like to have a loader that is hidden when all the widgets complete fetching the data and to be notified when an error has occured.

Comment: try `FutureBuilder` widget.

Comment: FutureBuilder is the answer.. refer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52081029

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable that is either set to true or false. Then instead of directly returning the widget, use a ternary operator that checks whether loading is true or not. If it is, then show a loading widget that you may either create yourself or import from the flutter spinkit package. Now, when the event that starts the fetching of data is triggered you set the state of that boolean to true which triggers the build function that shows the loading widget. As soon as the data is fetched change the state back and you are done!